# Как отправить сообщение конкретному клиенту?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, redis

Пытаюсь сделать личные сообщения на сайте в реальном времени. 
Вот код клиента:

```
    jQuery(function($) {
    // open a socket connection
    var socket = new io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {
        'reconnection': true,
        'reconnectionDelay': 1000,
        'reconnectionDelayMax' : 5000,
        'reconnectionAttempts': 5
    });

    // when user connect, store the user id and name
    socket.on('connect', function (user) {
        socket.emit('join', {id: "<?= Auth::user()->id ?>", name: "<?= Auth::user()->login ?>"});
    });

    $('input[name=message]').keyup(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var code = ev.which;
        if (code == 13) {
            var message = $(this).val();
            if (message.trim() !== '') {
                socket.emit('chat.send.message', {msg: message, nickname: '<?= Auth::user()->login ?>'});
                $(this).val('');
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    });

    // wait for a new message and append into each connection chat window
    socket.on('chat.message', function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if(data.hasOwnProperty('system')) {
            toastr["success"](data.msg);
        } else {
            var nick = '<?= Auth::user()->login ?>';
            if (nick == data.nickname) {
                $('.chat').append('<div class="bubble me">' + data.msg + '</div>');
            } else {
                $('.chat').append('<div class="bubble you">' + data.msg + '</div>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

А это код сервера:

```
var app     = require('express')(),
http    = require('http').Server(app),
io      = require('socket.io')(http),
Redis   = require('ioredis'),
redis   = new Redis();

var port = 8080,
users = nicknames = {};

http.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on *:' + port);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('join', function (user) {

    console.info('New client connected (id=' + user.id + ' (' + user.name + ') => socket=' + socket.id + ').');

    // save socket to emit later on a specific one
    socket.userId   = user.id;
    socket.nickname = user.name;

    users[user.id] = socket;

    // store connected nicknames
    nicknames[user.id] = {
        'nickname': user.name,
        'socketId': socket.id,
    };


    function updateNicknames() {
        // send connected users to all sockets to display in nickname list
        io.sockets.emit('chat.users', nicknames);
    }

    updateNicknames();


    // subscribe connected user to a specific channel, later he can receive message directly from our ChatController
    redis.subscribe(['chat.message', 'chat.private'], function (err, count) {
        console.log(user);
    });

    // get messages send by ChatController
    redis.on("message", function (channel, message) {
        console.log('Receive message %s from system in channel %s', message, channel);

        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });


    // get user sent message and broadcast to all connected users
    socket.on('chat.send.message', function (message) {
        console.log('Receive message ' + message.msg + ' from user in channel chat.message');

        io.sockets.emit('chat.message', JSON.stringify(message));
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        if( ! socket.nickname) return;

        delete users[user.id];
        delete nicknames[user.id];

        updateNicknames();

        console.info('Client gone (id=' + user.id+ ' => socket=' + socket.id + ').');
    });
   });
 });
```

Проблема в том, что приватные сообщения не получается. Если отправляю одному человеку сообщение, то оно доходит всем. Как сделать, что бы я мог выбрать пользователя, скажем по логину и переписываться только с ним. Соответственно что бы никто не смог прочитать переписку.